# C addressing and refs

Tags: c, pointers

Question about the 8-bit and 16-bit values.

I have the function:

```
get( uint8 *temp );
```

I will use it like this:

```
uint16 getTemp;
get( (uint8*) &getTemp );
```

Will this work or why not use a uint8 directly for getTemp and skip the typecasting here?
Could it be a bigger address for the pointer in this case thats why  but still can the value getTemp even be used like: `getTemp == 0x200U`?

Comment: Your syntax is screwed up.

Comment: There is no context so nobody can tell if this makes sense or not. Moste likely it doesn't: generally, it would be a very bad idea to pass a pointer to a larger type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address size will remain the same and the address value as well.

There are two issues however:

1. assignment will modify only half of the variable
2. it will work differently on little endian architecture (low 8 bits will be set) and big endian architecture (high 8 bits will be set).

Comment: Thanks, this was what i needed, i also guessed this will only get half of the value in my case the little endian.